# ERROR: Error installing json: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: json, rubygems, cygwin

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150301-5056-xgqsy7.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
rm -f
rm -f generator.so  *.o  *.bak mkmf.log .*.time

make "DESTDIR="
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backw ard -I/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -DJSON_GENERATOR     -ggdb -O2 -pipe  -Wimplicit-function-declaration    -o generator.o -c generator.c
rm -f generator.so
gcc -shared -o generator.so generator.o -L. -L/usr/lib -L. -fstack-pro tector -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable- auto-import    -lruby200  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/l d: cannot find -lcrypt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:232: recipe for target 'generator.so' failed
make: *** [generator.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/Saumyash/.gem/ruby/gems/json- 1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/Saumyash/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-cygwin/js on-1.8.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Did you read the above thing? especially `l d: cannot find -lcrypt`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `libcrypt-devel`. After that it will build fine.